# SimpleXML: Working with XML containing namespaces

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, simplexml

I am trying to get to the geo information off the google-picasa API. This is the original XML:

```
<georss:where>
  <gml:Point>
    <gml:pos>35.669998 139.770004</gml:pos>
  </gml:Point>
</georss:where>
```

I already have come this far, with:

```
$ns_geo=$item->children($namespace['georss']);
$geo=$ns_geo->children($namespace['gml']);
```

`var_dump($geo)` will output

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#34 (1) { 
  ["Point"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#30 (1) { 
    ["pos"]=> string(18) "52.373801 4.890935" 
  } 
}
```

but

```
echo (string)$geo->position or (string)$geo->position->pos;
```

will give me nothing. Is there something obvious that i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could work with XPath and [`registerXPathNamespace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerXPathNamespace.php):

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("georss", "http://www.georss.org/georss");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("gml", "http://www.opengis.net/gml");
$pos = $xml->xpath("/georss:where/gml:Point/gml:pos");
```

From the docs, emphasis mine:

> registerXPathNamespace […] Creates a prefix/ns context **for the next XPath query**.

More ways to handle namespaces in SimpleXML can be found here, for example:
[Stuart Herbert On PHP - Using SimpleXML To Parse RSS Feeds](http://blog.stuartherbert.com/php/2007/01/07/using-simplexml-to-parse-rss-feeds/)

Comment: thanks, I came to the same conclusion
this worked $geo = $feed->xpath('//gml:pos');echo $geo[0];
maybe the other way can't handle nested namespace elements

Comment: actually, I misspelled something.$geo->point should be $geo->Point
(uppercase)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $geo->pos[0];
```

Comment: This method won't access namespaces

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it without using xpath:

```
$georss = $photo->children('http://www.georss.org/georss');
$coords;
if($georss->count()>0) {
    $gml = $georss->children('http://www.opengis.net/gml');
    if($gml->count()>0) {
        if(isset($gml->Point->pos)) {
            $coords = $gml->Point->pos;
        }
    }
}
```