# hostip.info - Parse API response with SimpeXML

Tags: php, xml, api, simplexml

I'm trying to parse the xml response of http://api.hostip.info/?ip=12.215.42.19 with [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) but I can't seem to get it work.

**Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<HostipLookupResultSet version="1.0.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.hostip.info/api/hostip-1.0.1.xsd">
 <gml:description>This is the Hostip Lookup Service</gml:description>
 <gml:name>hostip</gml:name>
 <gml:boundedBy>
  <gml:Null>inapplicable</gml:Null>
 </gml:boundedBy>
 <gml:featureMember>

  <Hostip>
   <ip>12.215.42.19</ip>
   <gml:name>Sugar Grove, IL</gml:name>
   <countryName>UNITED STATES</countryName>
   <countryAbbrev>US</countryAbbrev>
   <!-- Co-ordinates are available as lng,lat -->
   <ipLocation>

    <gml:pointProperty>
     <gml:Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
      <gml:coordinates>-88.4588,41.7696</gml:coordinates>
     </gml:Point>
    </gml:pointProperty>
   </ipLocation>
  </Hostip>
 </gml:featureMember>

</HostipLookupResultSet>
```

Can someone help me to access for instance Hostip>ipLocation>pointProperty>Point>coordinates

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleXML: Working with XML containing namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014835/simplexml-working-with-xml-containing-namespaces)

Comment: great I think that'll help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways (which are available elsewhere on SO by searching!).

**XPath** (a very basic on to demonstrate)

```
$coords = $xml->xpath('//gml:coordinates');
echo $coords[0];
```

**"Simple" XML** (not so simple)

```
echo $xml
    ->children('gml', TRUE)->featureMember
    ->children('', TRUE)->Hostip->ipLocation
    ->children('gml', TRUE)->pointProperty->Point->coordinates;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access attributes like array
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-simplexml-element-attributes/
like (im not sure with your example)

```
Hostip->ipLocation->gml['pointproperty']
```

Comment: OP isnt looking to fetch an attribute and linked article doesnt address how to fetch namespaced elements