# PHP XML Not loading using XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm loading a XML file as follows:

```
$places=simplexml_load_file("http://www.43places.com/service/search_places?api_key=1234&q=america");
$allPlaces=$places->xpath('//place');
foreach($allPlaces as $title)
{
    echo "a";
}
```

Simply to test it, the file is correctly loading, you can see the XML file [here](http://www.43places.com/service/search_places?api_key=1234&q=america).

Any idea why it is not looping??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why XPath wouldn't work but, based on the XML structure I see there, you really don't need XPath.  SimpleXMLElements can be a little bearish but it would be extremely easy to use this alternative loop structure:

```
foreach( $places->place as $place )
{
    echo "a";
}
```

And you won't need the overhead of an xpath query at all; the structure you want is already right there.

Answer (score 2):

It's not looping because it does not return any nodes. So why is that?

Technically, the `<place>` element is within a namespace of it's own: `http://www.43places.com/xml/2005/rc#`, so `place` is only the so called *local name* of the element and not it's full name. Xpath does not accept full names but you can register a namespace for xpath operations with a name (prefix) of your choice and then use it in the xpath query:

```
$places->registerXPathNamespace("a", "http://www.43places.com/xml/2005/rc#");
$allPlaces = $places->xpath('//a:place');
```

This query now selects the 20 or so `place` elements you're looking for.

See as well: [SimpleXML: Working with XML containing namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2014835/367456).